# highcharts date not displayed properly on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult getJSONresult(string data)
            {

                Entities entities = new Entities();

                List<MyModel> vendlist = new List<MyModel>();

                var vnlist = (from c in entities.table
                              select c);


                foreach (var item in vnlist)
                {
                    MyModel temp = new MyModel();

                    temp.x= item.TimeofArrival;
                    temp.y= item.Value;

                    vendlist.Add(temp);
                }

                string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(vendlist);

                return Json(output);
            }
```

// output is returning-

```
"[{\"x\":\"\\/Date(1502998529947)\\/\",\"y\":3.85},
 {\"x\":\"\\/Date(1502998546947)\\/\",\"y\":3.85},
 {\"x\":\"\\/Date(1502998563937)\\/\",\"y\":3.85},
 {\"x\":\"\\/Date(1502998580940)\\/\",\"y\":3.85},
 {\"x\":\"\\/Date(1502998597950)\\/\",\"y\":3.85}"
```

View:

```
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    $.ajax({
                url: '/MyTemplate2/getJSONresult',
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //result
                    console.log("Data :" + data);

                    displaydata(data);
// output received: 
/*"[{"x":"\ /Date(1502998529947)\ /","y":3.85},
{"x":"\/Date(1502998546947)\ /","y":3.85},
{"x":"\/Date(1502998563937)\ /","y":3.85}....}]"*/

                }, error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error.responseText);
                }
            });

            function displaydata(data) {


       Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Time'
                        },
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'data'
                        }
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            turboThreshold: 0
                        },
                        area: {
                            fillColor: {
                                linearGradient: {
                                    x1: 0,
                                    y1: 0,
                                    x2: 0,
                                    y2: 1
                                },
                                stops: [
                                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                                ]
                            },
                            marker: {
                                radius: 2
                            },
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            threshold: null
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: data
                    }]
                });

            }
```

The x axis is not being plotted properly. 
Note:The JSON format being passed from controller has forward and backward slashes that could be the source of the problem.

Does it have anything to do with the improper date format, and if so how to rectify it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can I check what is 'item.TimeofArrival' data type? im bit confused why do we get "\/Date(1502998529947)\/" with '\/'

Comment: @PonmudiVN its in datetime. Im taking it frm sql server. Its in utc time

Comment: I don't have sql server to test. Here is an hack, you can format the data like 
**data.forEach((d,i)=>{data[i].x = d.x.match(/\d\d*/g)});**
Here data 'x' is updated to contain string only. Add this code before calling displayData.
This is not a solution just a workaround

Comment: Im getting an error on the forEach : data.forEach is not a function

Comment: parse the string to form the JSON. https://jsfiddle.net/ponmudi/60uv7pgc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Posting the solution.
In the controller, convert the received time to string so that you can later convert it to the format supported by Highcharts and not C# default format.

```
foreach (var item in vnlist)
                {
                    MyModel temp = new MyModel();

                    temp.x= item.TimeofArrival.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");//change the datatype of x to string
                    temp.y= item.Value;

                    vendlist.Add(temp);
                }
```

As the controller is returning JSON string, parse it in the View, then convert 'x' to datetime by iterating through it.

```
 function displaydata(data) {
data = JSON.parse(data);
data.forEach(function (element, index) {
                element.x = new Date(element['x']).getTime();
                element.y = +element['y'];

            });
```